# Create custom getter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I make a field in a document have a custom getter? I want the `subtotal` field to return `productTotal + tax` anytime I get `subtotal`.

```
const item = new mongoose.Schema({
    payment: {
        productTotal: Number,
        tax: Number,
        subtotal: Number, // (productTotal + tax)
    }
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', item);
```

I can't use virtualization since I want to also be able to use `find` on `subtotal`.

Comment: If you want to be able to use `find`, you can't use a getter (which is actually a virtual field). You will have to actually save it, you can set the value according to other fields during save or update operations using mongoose [middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've never used mongoose but we can practicly create a prototype for Item model I'm guessing maybe this code would work?

```js
const item = new mongoose.Schema({
  payment: {
    productTotal: Number,
    tax: Number,
  },
});
const Item = mongoose.model("Item", item);
Item.prototype.subtotal = function () {
  return this.payment.productTotal + this.payment.tax;
};

const newItem = new Item({ payment: { productTotal: 10, tax: 10 } });
// Obv you need to call it as function :)
console.log(newItem.subtotal());
```

I've checked the docs from mongoose couldn't find anything related with getter